# How to calculate the difference of two SELECTs in SQL (Access, JetSQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, jet-sql

I need to get the difference of two `SUM...WHERE` queries from the same table join:

```
SELECT SUM(Service_template.Service_fee)
FROM (Service_template LEFT JOIN Service ON Service_template.Service_Code = Service.Service_Code) LEFT JOIN Bill ON Service.Service_ID = Bill.Service_ID
WHERE Bill.Service_ID IS NOT NULL
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(Service_template.Service_fee)
FROM (Service_template LEFT JOIN Service ON Service_template.Service_Code = Service.Service_Code) LEFT JOIN Bill ON Service.Service_ID = Bill.Service_ID
```

I've tried using `UNION`, but it returns two rows, not two columns I can make calculations on.

How do I go about doing it? I feel I am missing something trivial, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all three values, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(b.Service_ID IS NOT NULL, st.Service_fee, 0)) as total_1,
       SUM(b.Service_Id) as total_2,
       SUM(IIF(b.Service_ID IS NULL, st.Service_fee, 0)) as diff      
FROM (Service_template as st LEFT JOIN
      Service as s
      ON st.Service_Code = s.Service_Code
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Bill as b
     ON s.Service_ID = b.Service_ID;
```

If you just want the `SUM()` where `Service_Id` is `NULL`, then:

```
SELECT SUM(b.Service_Id) as diff      
FROM (Service_template as st LEFT JOIN
      Service as s
      ON st.Service_Code = s.Service_Code
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Bill as b
     ON s.Service_ID = b.Service_ID
WHERE b.Service_ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Select
  Sum(T1.Sum1),
  Sum(T2.Sum2),
  Sum(T1.Sum1) - Sum(T2.Sum2) As Diff1,
  Sum(T2.Sum2) - Sum(T1.Sum1) As Diff2
From
  (SELECT SUM(Service_template.Service_fee) As Sum1 FROM (Service_template LEFT JOIN Service ON Service_template.Service_Code = Service.Service_Code) LEFT JOIN Bill ON Service.Service_ID = Bill.Service_ID WHERE Bill.Service_ID IS NOT NULL) As T1,
  (SELECT SUM(Service_template.Service_fee) As Sum2 FROM (Service_template LEFT JOIN Service ON Service_template.Service_Code = Service.Service_Code) LEFT JOIN Bill ON Service.Service_ID = Bill.Service_ID) As T2
```

Comment: Thanks, chose @gordon-linoff 's solution